# stegnography code in matlab for LSB in rgb values

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

What I want is to input a text file and convert my character in to binary values and then I input an image extract its pixel on there RGB values convert those values in binary and then LSB of Red I enter one bit of character and then Green and blue after that.
Initially I start testing by passing only "Hello" text instead of whole text file.
However I got black image at the end.
I know my code is wrong somewhere.

I want decoding code as well.
Any type of help would be appreciated.

```
imge=imread('peppers.png');
R = imge(:,:,1);
G = imge(:,:,2);
B = imge(:,:,3);
[r c p]=size(imge);
emb_img=zeros(size(imge));
Re = emb_img(:,:,1);
Gr = emb_img(:,:,2);
Bl = emb_img(:,:,3);
disp(imge(1,2));
str='hello'
df = dec2bin(str,8)
individualBits = df - '0';
ee=str2num(df);
len=length(ee);
rgbcounter = 1;
count=1;
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        for u=1:8
            if(count<=len)
                sec_msg = individualBits(count,1:8);
                bin = bitset(1,1,sec_msg(u));
                if rgbcounter==1
                    val = dec2bin(R(i,j));
                    val(8) = bin;
                    add_val = strcat(num2str(val), num2str(bin));
                    bin_nr = add_val;
                    dec = 0;
                    for f = 1 : length(bin_nr)
                        dec = dec + str2num(bin_nr(f)) * 2^(length(bin_nr) - f);
                    end
                    if(isempty(dec))
                        Re(i,j) = R(i,j);
                    else
                        Re(i,j) = dec;
                    end
                elseif rgbcounter==2
                    val = dec2bin(G(i,j));
                    val(8) = bin;
                    add_val = strcat(num2str(val), num2str(bin));
                    bin_nr = add_val;
                    dec = 0;
                    for f = 1 : length(bin_nr)
                        dec = dec + str2num(bin_nr(f)) * 2^(length(bin_nr) - f);
                    end
                    if(isempty(dec))
                        Gr(i,j)= G(i,j);
                    else
                        Gr(i,j) = dec;
                        disp(Gr(i,j));
                    end
                else
                    val = dec2bin(B(i,j));
                    val(8) = bin;
                    add_val = strcat(num2str(val), num2str(bin));
                    bin_nr = add_val;
                    dec = 0;
                    for f = 1 : length(bin_nr)
                        dec = dec + str2num(bin_nr(f)) * 2^(length(bin_nr) - f);
                    end
                    if(isempty(dec))
                        Bl(i,j) = B(i,j);
                    else
                        Bl(i,j) = dec;
                    end
                end
                if rgbcounter<=2
                    rgbcounter=rgbcounter+1;
                else
                    rgbcounter=1;
                end
                if u==8
                    count=count+1;
                end
            else
                break;
            end
        end
    end
end
emb_img = cat(3, Re, Gr, Bl);
disp(emb_img(1,2));
out_emd_img=imge;
imshow(emb_img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I refer to your question about bad display of the image, not to achieving the goal of your code. The image is black and white because it is in uint8 values but in double format. besides, the only pixels that took any color are at the top left of the image. You can display the image correctly and zoom in to see the colored pixels like this:

```
imshow(uint8(emb_img));
xlim([0 15])
ylim([0 15])
```

Comment: It gives me an distorted image.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if(count<=len)
    ...
else
    break
end
```

So once you have done 6 operations you always, for every number, break the loop.

Restart your variable!

```
if(count<=len)
    ...
else
    count=1;
    break
end
```

also, in the end, do:

```
imshow(emb_img/255);
```

for proper plotting.

Comment: It gives me infinite loop, actually you didn't see this line sec_msg = individualBits(count,1:8); here on first count I extract all my first character bits. for that I don't need  count = 1 on else.

Comment: @sumitkothia the code you posted **can not** give an infinite loop.

Comment: yes but after adding your code in else count = 1 gives me infinte loop

Comment: @sumitkothia it is impossible. Maximum iterations are `r*c*8`. A for loop can not iterate infinitely.

Comment: can you please run my code with your updates on your Matlab? Because i think the problem is somewhere in R G B assignments, count loop only runs 5 time but 8* 5 = 40 times value inserted.

Comment: @sumitkothia you refuse to listen. My solution solves that and I have explained why. If you do my change, the code runs, its just that your implemetation is very very very slow, and it will take maybe an hour to run, but its not infinite, its very slow.

Comment: ohk then i try for an hour and then let you know.

Comment: @sumitkothia I suggest you rethink your code and implement in faster

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or references that i can use?